# JUnit Tests: object not recreated between parameterized tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to test implementations of a `Collections` interface using JUnit4 `Parameterized` tests. My test class has two tests:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class CollectionsTest {

    private Collection<String> col;
    private Collection<String> other;

    public CollectionsTest(Collection<String> c, Collection<String> other) {
        this.col = c;
        this.other = other;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static java.util.Collection<Object[]> tokenStreams() {
        return (java.util.Collection<Object[]>) Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { 
            { new DSLinkedList<String>(), new DSLinkedList<String>() } });
    }

    @Test
    public final void isEmpty() {
        assertTrue(col.getClass().getName() + ".isEmpty() should return true when collection contains no elements", col.isEmpty()); 
        col.add("Stringthing");
        assertFalse(col.getClass().getName() + ".isEmpty() should return false when collection contains elements", col.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public final void size() {
        assertEquals(col.getClass().getName() + ".size() should be 0 for an empty collection.", 0, col.size());
        col.add("String");
        assertEquals(col.getClass().getName() + ".size() should be 1 for a collection with one element.", 1, col.size());       
    }
}
```

The second test (`size()`) always fails: at the time of the first assertion, `col` contains a single element `stringThing`, because I inserted an element in the `isEmpty()` test.

#### How do I clean the parameterized objects between tests?

If I wasn't using a parameterized test, I'd use `@Before` with a `setup()` method: should I be using reflection and a setup method here to recreate the `col` and `other` objects? (I haven't done this because I don't know which `Collection` implementation each test is running beforehand: if I have to manually write code using reflection to determine this, what's the point of Parameterized tests?)

My understanding is that the Parameterized tests call the constructor before each test, which should 'reset' my objects cleanly: why is this not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a late response. But I had the same dilemma and I solved it like this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class CollectionsTest {

    private Collection<String> col;
    private Collection<String> other;

    private Class<Collection> source1;
    private Class<Collection> source2;

    public CollectionsTest(Class<Collection> first, Class<Collection> second) {
        this.source1 = first;
        this.source2 = second;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> instancesToTest() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { 
                { DSLinkedList.class, DSLinkedList.class }, 
                { OtherCollection.class, MyCollection.class } 
        });
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.col = source1.newInstance();
        this.other = source2.newInstance();
    }

    . . .
```

This approach works as long as your classes have a default constructor (no arguments).
The `@Before setup()` method gets called before each test and creates a new instance for your objects.

To use non-default constructors yo can use `getConstructor()` to choose which constructor you want:

```
this.col = source1.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("Hello object");
```

You can create new objects within your tests too, using the same technique (e.g. `Collection<String> c1 = source1.newInstance()`), those tests have to throw an `Exception` (you will get a compile time error if they don't)

Answer (score 2):

In **Java 8** this can be done fairly cleanly using **lambda expressions** and the utility class `java.util.function.Supplier`. Instead of providing an instance of the parameter type, you provide a lambda which supplies a new instance each time it is evaluated. JUnit passes the lambda to the constructor for each test case, where a new instance is created with a call to `get()`.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class CollectionsTest {

  private Collection<String> col;
  private Collection<String> other;

  public CollectionsTest(Supplier<Collection<String>> c, Supplier<Collection<String>> other) {
    this.col = c.get();
    this.other = other.get();
}

@Parameterized.Parameters
public static java.util.Collection<Object[]> tokenStreams() {
    Supplier<Collection<String>> c1 = () -> new DSLinkedList<String>();
    Supplier<Collection<String>> c2 = () -> new DSLinkedList<String>();

    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { { c1, c2 } });
}

@Test
public final void isEmpty() {
    assertTrue(col.getClass().getName() + ".isEmpty() should return true when collection contains no elements", col.isEmpty()); 
    col.add("Stringthing");
    assertFalse(col.getClass().getName() + ".isEmpty() should return false when collection contains elements", col.isEmpty());
}

@Test
public final void size() {
    assertEquals(col.getClass().getName() + ".size() should be 0 for an empty collection.", 0, col.size());
    col.add("String");
    assertEquals(col.getClass().getName() + ".size() should be 1 for a collection with one element.", 1, col.size());       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameterized creates a new CollectionsTest object before each tests and calls the constructor, but it passes the same DSLinkedList objects each time, tokenStreams() is called only once for whole testcase. You should clean the lists in the constructor yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are changing the member variable value though. So, are you expecting the constructor to be called before each test? Also, as per the documentation of Parameterized. Your Test class `instance` would be provided with the data values in the @Parameters method. It isnt every test it is the `instance` of the class.

[Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc_40/index.html?org/junit/runners/Parameterized.Parameters.html)